# Python nested list of lists value operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've two nested list of lists in the form of

```
[ 
  [ [.3 .1 .2]
    [.2 .1 .5] 
    ... (224 lists)
    [.6 .9 .4] ]

    ... (224 lists)

  [ [.1 .7 .5]
    [.3 .8 .4]
    ... (224 lists)
    [.2 .6 .9] ]  
]
```

I want to do following operations on it. step 1 :

```
a = 1st list items
b = 2nd list items

[ 
  [ [a0-b0 a1-b1 a2-b2]
    [.. .. ..]
    ... (224 lists)
    [.. .. ..] ]

    ... (224 lists)

  [ [.. .. ..]
    [.. .. ..]
    ... (224 lists)
    [.. .. ..] ]  
]
```

Step 2 : Let a0-b0 = A0, a1-b1 = B0 , a2-b2 = C0.

```
[  [sqrt(A0**2+B0**2+C0**2) .. ..]
   ... (224 lists)
   [.. .. ..]
]
```

Step 3 :

```
# Let sqrt(A0**2+B0**2+C0**2) = z. So we get :
[  [z0 z1 z2]
   ... (224 lists)
   [.. .. ..]
]
```

In the third step we want to sum all the elements of the nested lists.

My try :

```
# two nested lists are tupfl and t2
difflay1 = [ [ [0 for i in range(3)] for i in range(224)] for i in range(224)]
rtsqlay2 = [ [0 for i in range(3)] for i in range(224)]

for i in range(224):
    for j in range(224):
        for k in range(3):
            difflay1[i][j][k] = tupfl[i][j][k] - t2[i][j][k]
for i in range(224):
    for j in range(224):
        for k in range(3):
            alpha = difflay1[i][j][0]
            beta = difflay1[i][j][1]
            theta = difflay1[i][j][2]
            rtsqlay2[i][k] = math.sqrt(alpha**2 + beta**2 + theta**2)

def nested_sum(L):
    total = 0  
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            total += nested_sum(i)
        else:
            total += i
    return total
print(nested_sum(rtsqlay2))
```

I'm not sure whether this code works according to what I exactly want. However, it prints some floating points. If this is not right, where's the error or how to proceed ?

Comment: `math.sqrt(alpha**2 + beta**2 + theta**2)` that introduces some floating points...

Comment: I can't tell the quality of the code. Here we try to solve specific issues.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using numpy? Using numpy arrays would make your lists use less space, the code run faster, and make it easier to run.

To get difflay1 and rtsqlay2, you could do the following instead of a loop

```
difflay1 = tufpl - t2
rtsqlay2 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(difflay1),axis=2))
```

for doing nested sum, there is already a function to do this called `np.sum(L)`

overall, your code would look like:

```
import numpy as np

tupfl = np.array(tupfl)
t2 = np.array(t2)
difflay1 = tufpl - t2
rtsqlay2 = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(difflay1),axis=2))
print(np.sum(rtsqlay2))
```

it is shorter and easier to debug since you can immediately see any issues. For example, in your code, you have rtsqlay2 defined as a list of lists instead of a list of list of lists. As a result, for each i and k `rtsqlay2[i][k]` is being defined 224 times, once for each value of j, and only keeping the last one. This indicates code not behaving as desired, but wouldn't throw an error. Which numpy arrays, these errors become easier to catch